# How to play sound when chronometer reaches certain time?

Tags: java, android

Let's say that I need to play a sound when chronometer is at 30 seconds, how do I do it? Thanks! ♥ 
This doesn't work:

```
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
                int c = 0;
                c++;
                if(c == 30) {
                    c = 0;
                    beep.start();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: When you say "this doesn't work", what is not working? Are you getting an error? What behavior are you expecting and what behavior are you getting? Please add some more detail to your question.

Comment: It just doesn't play the sound. Huh.

Answer (score 1):

The chronometer does not tick once per second, you have to calculate the elapsed time yourself.

```
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        int beeps = 1;
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            long myElapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
            if(myElapsedMillis / 30000 >= beeps) {
                beep.start();
                beeps++;
            }
        }
    });
```